# Finding the image of multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be defined by the equation

$$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$$

Let $A$ be the set consisting of all $(x,y)$ with $x \gt 0$.

and $g: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ by the equation

$$g(x,y)=(e^x\operatorname{cos}y,e^x\operatorname{sin}y)$$

Let $B$ be the set consisting of all $(x,y)$ with $0\lt y\lt 2\pi$.

What are the sets $C=f(A)$ and $D=g(B)$?

$D$ is easier to think because I can think of $e^x$ as the radius and then there would be circles without the line $x\ge 0$. However, I'm not sure how to formally prove this idea. Meanwhile, for $C$, I'm having trouble interpreting the image of the set $A$. I could think of the complex function $z^2$ but I don't know how to find the image of the set with only positive real part. Less so in the $\mathbb{R^2}$, I don't know how to show the image. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Here you can find an image of C: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28x%5E2-y%5E2%2C2xy%29+for+x%3E0+and+y%3E0
And you can build an image of D.

Comment: @Emilio Novati Thanks but I'm trying to make an analytical statement. Something like C={...}.

Comment: You can fix $y=k$ and you see that the $x-$coordinate of $C$ is a parabola and the $y-$ coordinate is a stright line. Sorry, but I don't see what you can do more.